# Retrieve the 68 built-in functions directly in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Command `dir(__builtins__)` just list all the 151 builtin libraries.

```
len(dir(__builtins__)) # output 151
```

However, It lists 68 built-in functions in [2. Built-in Functions — Python 3.6.2 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html)

I tried to get the functions from `dir(__builtins__)` as the following steps:

```
#I hardtyped the functions as comparition.
officical_builtin_functions = ['abs','all',....]
y = official_builtin_functions
len(y) #output:68
# get official builtin functions from python_builtin_library
dir(__builtins__).index('abs') #output:79
qualified_functions = python_builtin_library[79:]
qualified_functions.pop('exit')
qualified_functions.pop('credits')
qualified_functions.pop('copyright')
qualified_functions.pop('quit')
qualified_functions.pop('license')
quilified_functions.append('__import__')
# then get the 68 qualified_functions from dir(__builtins__)
```

How to list the 68 built-in functions directly?

Comment: You really can't. Not all of the builtin "functions" are "functions", etc. Also, `dir(__builtins__)` is not ordered.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Actually `dir()` sorts the list alphabetically.

Comment: yes,only 42 real builtin functions. @AnttiHaapala

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach in Python 3.5 would be to list objects that have the `__module__` attribute and it set to `builtins` and lowercase name:

```
>>> sorted(k for k, v in vars(__builtins__).items()
           if k.islower() and getattr(v, '__module__', '') == 'builtins')
['__build_class__', '__import__', 'abs', 'all', 'any', 'ascii', 'bin', 'bool', 'bytearray',
 'bytes', 'callable', 'chr', 'classmethod', 'compile', 'complex', 'delattr', 'dict', 'dir', 
 'divmod', 'enumerate', 'eval', 'exec', 'filter', 'float', 'format', 'frozenset', 'getattr', 
 'globals', 'hasattr', 'hash', 'hex', 'id', 'input', 'int', 'isinstance', 'issubclass',
 'iter', 'len', 'list', 'locals', 'map', 'max', 'memoryview', 'min', 'next', 'object', 'oct',
 'ord', 'pow', 'print', 'property', 'range', 'repr', 'reversed', 'round', 'set', 'setattr',
 'slice', 'sorted', 'staticmethod', 'str', 'sum', 'super', 'tuple', 'type', 'vars', 'zip']
```

Notice that `__import__` is listed in the docs but `__build_class__` is not. 67 names on Python 3.5. The list in the docs has 68 names... This is also because `help` and `open` from the documentation do not match my filter, as `open` is from module `io` and `help` is from site builtins; actually the documentation is wrong, because `help` need not be available:

```
% python3 -S
Python 3.5.3 (default, Jan 19 2017, 14:11:04) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170118] on linux
>>> help
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'help' is not defined
```

Likewise many exception types are always available, even though they're not listed there.

Answer (score 2):

I tried being smart about it but partially failed, but still an interesting find, so here it is:

```
import types
b = [i for i in dir(__builtins__) if isinstance(eval(i), types.BuiltinFunctionType)]
```

This returns a list of 42 items for me in python 3.5.3

Without using `types`, a nice seperator is to check if the items in `__builtins__` start with a lowercase letter, that usually indicates a function, so

```
b = [i for i in dir(__builtins__) if i[0].islower()]
```

Returns 72 items for me, perhaps it's more complete than the documentation is? My guess would be yes. Check it out for yourself to test these ideas

Comment: Tested, find a interesting comprehension: b = [ i for in in dir(__builtins__) if type(eval(i)) == type(eval)]

Comment: @DFK interesting, that gives the exact same result as my first example

Answer (score 2):

Technically, there are only 42 (in 3.4) or so builtin functions and methods in Python. The rest of the list is builtin variables and typess:

```
real_builtins = [e for e in dir(__builtins__) if isinstance(eval(e), type(vars))]
len(real_builtins)
# 42
real_builtins[:5] + real_builtins[-5:]
# ['__build_class__', '__import__', 'abs', 'all', 'any',
#  'round', 'setattr', 'sorted', 'sum', 'vars']
type(abs)
#<class 'builtin_function_or_method'>
```

Note that `zip` or `int`, for example, are not really functions. They are constructors of the namesake builtin data types:

```
type(zip)
# <class 'type'>
type(int)
# <class 'int'>
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to filter it (mostly) by functionality and came up with:

```
from inspect import isclass

documented_builtins = [x
    for x in dir(__builtins__) if not x.startswith('__') and (
        lambda y: callable(y) and not(isclass(y) and issubclass(y,
            BaseException)))(eval(x))
]

print(documented_builtins)
```

It produces the same 72 items that @OferSadan's simple `i[0].islower()` filter produces! (+1)

Additions are: `copyright`, `credits`, `exit`, `license` and `quit`

Deletions are: `__import__`

If you eliminate the `not x.startswith('__')` test, you get back `__import__` but you also get `__build_class__` and `__loader__`